# why it doesn't print ? LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures

i have a problem that the method in LinkedList class don't print anything.. and i'm trying hard to know what's the problem i hope someone help

the main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LLnode a = new LLnode(10);
        LLnode b = new LLnode(20);
        LLnode c = new LLnode(50);
        LinkedList List1 = new LinkedList();
      
      List1.printAllNodes();
    }
}
```

LinkedList class

```
public class LinkedList {
   
   private LLnode head;
   
  public LLnode gethead() {
        return this.head;
    }
    public void sethead(LLnode LLnode) {
        this.head = LLnode;
    }
   // Constructor
   public LinkedList() {
      head = null;
   }
   // Example Method to check if list is empty
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return head == null;
   }
   
   public void printAllNodes() {
    LLnode helpPtr = head;
    while (helpPtr != null) {
        System.out.print(helpPtr.getdata() + " ");
        helpPtr = helpPtr.getnext();
   }
```

why it dosn't print i tried so hard

Comment: this is the LLnode class Linked List class 


public class LLnode {
    private int data;
    private LLnode next;
    
   public LLnode getnext() {
        return this.next;
    }
    public void setnext(LLnode LLnode) {
        this.next = LLnode;
    }
    
   public int getdata() {
        return this.data;
    }
    public void setData(LLnode LLnode) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
   public LLnode (int i){
       this( i ,null);
   }
   
   public LLnode(int i, LLnode n) {
      data = i;
      next = n;
   }

Comment: You haven't added anything to the `List1`... It is empty! Your class should have a method `add` in addition to `setHead`, but you haven't even made use of `setHead`.

Comment: i added in LLnode

Comment: Where? It's not in the code you posted...

Comment: i added it as a comment

Answer (score 4):

This is because you never add any nodes to your LinkedList.

Code could be as follows. Beware, nodes will be added at the beginning of list.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LLnode a = new LLnode(10);
    LLnode b = new LLnode(20);
    LLnode c = new LLnode(50);
    LinkedList List1 = new LinkedList();
    List1.add(a).add(b).add(c);
  
  List1.printAllNodes();
}
```

}

LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList {
   
   private LLnode head;
   
  public LLnode gethead() {
        return this.head;
    }
    public void sethead(LLnode LLnode) {
        this.head = LLnode;
    }
   // Constructor
   public LinkedList() {
      head = null;
   }
   // Example Method to check if list is empty
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return head == null;
   }
   
   public LinkedList add(LLnode node){
       LLnode oldHead = this.head();
       this.head = node;
       node.setNext(oldHead);
       return this;
   }

   public void printAllNodes() {
    LLnode helpPtr = head;
    while (helpPtr != null) {
        System.out.print(helpPtr.getdata() + " ");
        helpPtr = helpPtr.getnext();
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean in oldHead? in add method

Comment: You are adding a new node at the beginning of the LinkedList. So at the end of add, the head of list has to be the element you add. And the added element must be linked to the remaining of the list. Thus you have to "save" the reference of the old head, set new node as head and set old head as successor to added node. That is exactly what I do in add() method 

Comment: To add node [n] to [a]->[b]->[c] list you save [a] as old head, set [n] as new head and set [a] as successor of [n]. This gives you [n]->[a]->[b]->[c].